# check/uncheck radio button based on values from ui datepicker angularjs

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to set date on click of radio button
currently I'm using below code which checks max and min dates which are predefined

1. tpl.html file

   ```
   <uib-datepicker ng-model="dateSelector.endDate" 
   maxdate="dateSelector.maxDate"min-date="dateSelector.minDate" show-
   weeks="true" class="well well-sm display-inline-block" 
   customclass="dateSelector.getDayClass(date, mode)"/>
   ```
2. Controller file

   ```
   getDayClass: function (date, mode) 
    {
      if (mode === 'day') 
        {
                   debugger;
                   $scope.fcount = $scope.fcount + 1;
                   console.log($scope.fcount);
                   if ($scope.dateSelector.startDate && $scope.dateSelector.endDate) {
                       if (date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) >= $scope.dateSelector.startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) &&
                           date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) <= $scope.dateSelector.endDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) {
                           //return 'daterange';
                           return '';
                       }
                   }
               }
               return '';
           }
   ```

This is the date range I've tested with

start date: 01/01/2016
End date : 10/05/2016

this code is working fine but above function is getting fired 168 times. I am unable to understand this behaviour.

I am new to SO Please bar me with formatting